# Find specific comments Entries in HTML code using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, comments, html-parsing

I am trying to parse the specific entries from the comments session from HTML. I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to do it. I get stuck after I was able to extract the comment part. Here's an example:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xqtc.png)

```
import urllib
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"), 'html.parser')
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
```

Do you guys know how can I get the correct info? Appreciate it!!

Comment: Do all the comments have this specific format ?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same format; but there are multiple Blocks of Comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen all the html's file content, but since all the comments are in the same format maybe you can parse them directly as strings like so:

```
# parse the comments
for comment in comments:
    for line in comment.splitlines():
        if ':' in line:
            attrib, val = line.strip().rsplit(':',1)
            print '{} -> {}'.format(attrib, val.strip(','))
```